ONVIF Discovery
I am writing code to send a Probe message to find my Onvif camera on the network. The message is sent over UDP to a multicast address "239.255.255.250" and UDP port 3702. I have succeeded to connect to the camera and to send the message. However no response from the camera.
The error message is WSA_IO_INCOMPLETE. I have also tryed with INFINITE timeout. What am I missing?
Here is my code:
static int RecvAnswer(SOCKET sfd, WSABUF wsarecvBuf, LPDWORD pNumberOfBytesRecvd) {
    int err = 0;
    int iResult = 0;
    DWORD Flags = 0;
    err = 0;
    DWORD cTransfer = 0;
    //char buf[256];

    ZeroMemory(wsarecvBuf.buf, RECV_BUF);
    iResult = WSARecv(sfd, &wsarecvBuf, 1, pNumberOfBytesRecvd, &Flags, &RecvOverlapped, NULL);
    if (SOCKET_ERROR == iResult) {
        err = WSAGetLastError();
        if (WSA_IO_PENDING != err) {
            std::cout << printf("WSARecv failed with error: %d\n", err);
            // WSAETIMEDOUT = 1060
            return 1;
        }
    }

    iResult = WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(1, &RecvOverlapped.hEvent, TRUE, 10000, TRUE);
    if (WSA_WAIT_FAILED == iResult) {
        err = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cout << printf("WSAWaitForMultipleEvents failed with error: %d\n", err);
        // WSA_INVALID_HANDLE = 6
        return 1;
    }

    iResult = WSAGetOverlappedResult(sfd, &RecvOverlapped, &cTransfer, FALSE, &Flags);
    if (FALSE == iResult) {
        err = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cout << printf("WSAGetOverlappedResult failed with error: %d\n", err);
        // WSA_IO_INCOMPLETE = 996
        return 1;
    }
    *pNumberOfBytesRecvd = cTransfer;

    WSAResetEvent(RecvOverlapped.hEvent);

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int iResult;
    char buffer[1024]{};
    uint16_t Port = 3702;
    const char IpAddress[] = "239.255.255.250";

    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != NO_ERROR) {
        std::cout << "WSAStartup failed to load!\n";
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    SOCKET sfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (sfd == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        std::cout << "Socket failur\n";
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    u_long iMode = 0;
    iResult = ioctlsocket(sfd, FIONBIO, &iMode);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
        closesocket(sfd);
        std::cout << "iMode failur\n";
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    TIMEVAL tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 2;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    setsockopt(sfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char*)&tv, sizeof(struct timeval));

    int optval = RECV_BUF;
    int optlen = sizeof(int);
    iResult = setsockopt(sfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (char*)&optval, optlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(sfd);
        std::cout << "Set Recieve buffer failur\n";
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    optval = SEND_BUF;
    iResult = setsockopt(sfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (char*)&optval, optlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(sfd);
        std::cout << "Set Send buffer failur\n";
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    sockaddr_in clientService;
    SecureZeroMemory(&clientService, sizeof(clientService));
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clientService.sin_port = htons(Port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, IpAddress, &clientService.sin_addr.s_addr);
    iResult = connect(sfd, (SOCKADDR*)&clientService, sizeof(clientService));
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        int error = WSAGetLastError();
        closesocket(sfd);
        std::cout << printf("Connect failur. Error code: %d\n", error);
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    fd_set readfds;
    fd_set writefds;
    fd_set exceptfds;
    tv.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    do {
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);
        FD_SET(sfd, &readfds);
        FD_ZERO(&writefds);
        FD_SET(sfd, &writefds);
        FD_ZERO(&exceptfds);
        FD_SET(sfd, &exceptfds);

        iResult = select(0, 0, &writefds, 0, &tv);
    } while (iResult == -1 && errno == EINTR);

    iResult = __WSAFDIsSet(sfd, &writefds);
    if (iResult != 1) {
        closesocket(sfd);
        std::cout << "Socket could not be includec in descriptors\n";
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    optval = 1;
    getsockopt(sfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, (char*)&optval, &optlen);
    std::cout << "Connected\n";

    SecureZeroMemory(&RecvOverlapped, sizeof(WSAOVERLAPPED));
    RecvOverlapped.hEvent = WSACreateEvent();
    if (RecvOverlapped.hEvent == NULL) {
        std::cout << printf("WSACreateEvent failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(sfd);
        return 0;
    }

    const char* discovery = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"\
        "<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing\">"\
          "<soap-env:Header>"\
            "<a:ReplyTo>"\
              "<a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>"\
            "</a:ReplyTo>"\
            "<a:Action a:mustUnderstand=\"1\">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery/Probe</a:Action>"\
            "<a:MessageID>uuid:%s</a:MessageID>"\
        "</soap:Header>"\
          "<soap-env:Body>"\
            "<wsd:Probe xmlns=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discover\">"\
              "<d:Types xmlns:d=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery\" xmlns:dp0=\"http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl\">"\
                "tds:Device</d:Types>"\
            "</d:Probe>"\
          "</soap-env:Body>"\
        "</soap-env:Envelope>";

    UUID uuid;
    RPC_STATUS status = UuidCreate(&uuid);
    if (0 != status) {
        closesocket(sfd);
        std::cout << "Create UUID failed\n";
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    char* str = nullptr;
    status = UuidToStringA(&uuid, (RPC_CSTR*)&str);
    if (0 != status) {
        closesocket(sfd);
        std::cout << "UuidToString failur\n";
        RpcStringFreeA((RPC_CSTR*)&str);
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    WSABUF wsasendBuf;
    wsasendBuf.buf = (char*)malloc(SEND_BUF);
    wsasendBuf.len = SEND_BUF;
    if (!wsasendBuf.buf) {
        closesocket(sfd);
        std::cout << "Send buffer failed\n";
        RpcStringFreeA((RPC_CSTR*)&str);
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    wsasendBuf.len = sprintf(wsasendBuf.buf, discovery, str);

    WSABUF wsarecvBuf;
    wsarecvBuf.buf = (char*)malloc(RECV_BUF);
    wsarecvBuf.len = RECV_BUF;

    if (send(sfd, wsasendBuf.buf, wsasendBuf.len, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        free(wsasendBuf.buf);
        free(wsarecvBuf.buf);
        closesocket(sfd);
        std::cout << "Sending request failed\n";
        RpcStringFreeA((RPC_CSTR*)&str);
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    int NumberOfBytesRecvd = 0;
    if (RecvAnswer(sfd, wsarecvBuf, (LPDWORD)&NumberOfBytesRecvd) != 0) {
        free(wsasendBuf.buf);
        free(wsarecvBuf.buf);
        closesocket(sfd);
        std::cout << "Recieving answer failed\n";
        RpcStringFreeA((RPC_CSTR*)&str);
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    free(wsasendBuf.buf);
    free(wsarecvBuf.buf);
    RpcStringFreeA((RPC_CSTR*)&str);
    WSACleanup();
    closesocket(sfd);

    system("pause");
}

Here is the output:
Connected
WSAGetOverlappedResult failed with error: 996
46Recieving answer failed
Press any key to continue . . .

I can't figure out where 46 comes from. It is printed in connection with the WSAGetOverlappedResult error message.
Does anyone have an idea for a solution.
